# How can Cortisol be administered in gaseous form?

Tags: steroids, inhalation, corticosteroids, cortisol, drug-administration

How can Cortisol be administered in gaseous form (inhalation)? What carrier gas would be adequate? CO, CO2, NO (Nitric Oxide)?

Comment: If you are thinking about inhaled glucocorticoids and the like, these things are not in a *gaseous* form: they are [aerosolized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerosol).